# How to Change #include Default File Path for Sub Folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

### **Context:**

I was following a tutorial in UE4.23 and at one point, we create sub-files in the `Source/ProjectName/` file.  Then, inside of the .cpp/.h files, we simply wrote `#include "Subfolder/File.h"` and it was recognized.  However, when working on my own project to practice (in UE4.26), I have to do this: `#include "../Subfolder/File.h"` to go up from the subfile, which tells me the include path is defaulting inside of the folder the file is in.

This causes annoying issues where Unreal will create a class and assume we start our path in the upper folder, causing a compile error with every new class until I manually change the include.

### **Question:**

How do I change the default include path of sub-folder files to start from the main folder?

**Example of desired result:** Setting default path to `"../Project/Source/ProjectName/"`

```
//thisclass.cpp file inside of "Source/ProjectName/Test/thisclass.cpp"

/* "Source/ProjectName/Framework/" */
#include "Framework/GameState.h" 

/* "Source/ProjectName/Player/" */
#include "Player/CharacterController.h"

//Must enter sub-folders as well, even though it's in the same subfolder
#include "Test/thisclass.h"
```

### **Side Notes:**

- My attempts to google the solution kept showing results for changing the project location, not changing directories or include paths.
- I'm pretty sure this is a Visual Studio issue, but I'm using it with Unreal, so I tagged both.

Answer (score 3):

Add **PublicIncludePaths** to your ***.Build.cs**

```
public class ProjectName: ModuleRules
{
    public ProjectName(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        //...
        PublicIncludePaths.AddRange(
        new string[] {
            "ProjectName",
            "ProjectName/Test"
        }
        //...
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this and experienced no changes.  I added it to the end of the default values Unreal had there; I then generated visual studio project files again in case it needed a refresh (still no changes).  Is there a step I'm missing or misunderstanding here?

Comment: I'll write how I understood your problem: You have a project ProjectName. You create "thisclass" in "Source/ProjectName/Test/". Then you compile the project and you get an error in thisclass.cpp something like "Unable to find path Test/thisclass.h". Then you change the path to "ProjectName/Test/thisclass.h" and the error goes away. Do you want to avoid such an error when adding new classes? You just need to add PublicIncludePaths with the name of the folder that is in "Source", i.e. "ProjectName".

Comment: This allows short #include. Or do you want to write almost the full path to the file?

Comment: You're mostly correct.  The difference is I'm not changing the path to "ProjectName/Test/thisclass.h" but instead just "thisclass.h" because they are in the same folder.  Consequently, if I have "thisotherclass" inside of "ProjectName/OtherTest/thisotherclass", inside of "thisotherclass.cpp", I would have to `#include "../Test/thisclass.h" in order to access it, but if they are in the same folder, then I would just do "thisclass.h".  For some reason, I have to tell it to go up a folder with "../" to access everything under "Source/ProjectName".  When following you answer, this did not change.

Comment: I had the same problem in UE5.03. I 1) added headers from "ProjectName/subA" via `#include "../subB/foo.h`, 2) built it, 3) added "ProjectName" to `PublicIncludePaths` in ***.Build,cs** 4) opened the Unreal Editor and refreshed Visual Studio Project files 5) Changed to `#include "subB/foo.h` 6) rebuilt and it worked even though I did not find it in the project properties.